# Draw a vertical line in PineScript v5 when returning time with 'time' and 'time_close'?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Here is an example code:

```
[pdOT, pdCT] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [time[1], time_close[1]])
```

How can I draw a line at `pdOT` and `cdOT`? I have tried using `line.new()`, `plot()`, `bgcolor()` all to no avail.

Comment: It would be better if you wrote what you would try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`time` functions return UNIX time in seconds, which is around `1688980013` today. You really want to draw lines using the bar index (Y position) and price level (X position).